# Web scraping with requests not working correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the html from [CNN](http://%3Chttps://www.cnn.com/%3E) for a personal project. I am using the *requests* library and am new to it. I have followed basic tutorials to get the HTML from CNN using requests, but keep getting responses that are different from the HTML I find when I inspect the webpage from my browser. Here is my code:

```
base_url = 'https://www.cnn.com/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

I am trying to get article titles from CNN, but this is my first issue. Thanks for the help!

*Update*
It seems that I know even less than I had initially assumed. My real question is: How do I extract titles from the CNN homepage? I've tried both answers, but the HTML from requests does not contain title information. How can I get the title information like what is in this picture (Screenshot of my browser)[Screenshot of cnn article title with accompanying html side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlYBR.png)

Comment: Is the response different every time? The webpage might be changing dynamically.

Comment: Your browser renders the HTML and executes e.g. the Javascript. Therefore what you get from your request is different.

Comment: As I noted at the bottom, I'm trying to get article titles from the main page. I can see the titles in the HTML on the web browser. However, the requests response doesn't contain the titles.

Comment: @Gabe This is entirely normal, as others have already said, this is due to browser rendering/JavaScript. The HTML you see in your browser doesn’t refute that. What matters is the HTML that you print. Speaking of, you could always share that. Also, use `.content`, not `.text`, when your request contains HTML you want to pass to a parser.

Comment: Content of web page load through `json`. so you have to scrape those data from json requests

Comment: If your matter is solved I suggest you mark one of answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Selenium ChromeDriver` to scrape `https://cnn.com`.

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("---CHROMEDRIVER-PATH---", options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://cnn.com/')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# Get Titles from HTML.
titles = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'cd__headline-text'})
print(titles)

# Close ChromeDriver.
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
[<span class="cd__headline-text"><strong>The West turned Aung San Suu Kyi into a saint. She was always going to disappoint </strong></span>, <span class="cd__headline-text"><strong>In Hindu-nationalist India, Muslims risk being branded infiltrators</strong></span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Johnson may have stormed to victory, but he's got a problem</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Impeachment heads to full House after historic vote</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Supreme Court to decide on Trump's financial records</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Michelle Obama's message for Thunberg after Trump mocks her</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Actor Danny Aiello dies at 86</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">The biggest risk at the North Pole isn't what you think</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">US city declares state of emergency after cyberattack </span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Reality TV show host arrested</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text">Big names in 2019 you may have mispronounced</span>, <span class="cd__headline-text"><strong>Morocco has Africa's 'first fully solar village'</strong></span>]
```

You can download ChromeDriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code and it worked for me.

```py
base_url = 'https://www.cnn.com/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Note that I have specified a `headers` parameter in `requests.get()`. All it does is that it tries to mimic a real browser so that the anti-scraping algorithms can't be able to detect it.
Hope this helps and if not then feel free to ask me in the comments. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked. CNN seems to recognize that you programmatically try to scrape the site and serves a 404 / missing page (with no content on it) instead of the homepage.

Try a headless browser like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/), e.g. like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://cnn.com')
html = driver.page_source
```